# SSL Cert with Google Colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, google-colaboratory

Working with Google Colab and trying to connect to an external API.

I have created a set of SSL certs and would like to deploy them, I have mounted my drive and referred the correct folder, but it is failing.

```
import betfairlightweight

from google.colab import drive 
from google.colab import files
#!pip install -U pyopenssl
drive.mount('content')
    # Change this certs path to wherever you're storing your certificates
certs_path = 'content/My Drive/betfair/'

# Change these login details to your own
my_username = XXXXX
my_password = XXXXX
my_app_key = XXXXX
trading = betfairlightweight.APIClient(username=my_username,
                                       password=my_password,
                                       app_key=my_app_key
                                       ,certs=certs_path)
```

The certs exist, however when I

```
certs_path ='content/My Drive/betfair'

!ls certs_path
```

I get the error

```
ls: cannot access 'certs_path': No such file or directory
```

How do I point to the correct certs folder in my google drive using Colab

Answer (score 0):

is the betfairlightweight.APIClient() call failing? Try making the path absolute: `/content/My Drive/betfair/`

The issue you're seeing with `!ls certs_path` is unrelated. When using the ! operator in Colab to run shell commands your python variables are not used. it is treating "certs_path" as just text.

try:

```
!ls /content/My Drive/betfair
```

to make sure things are mounted correctly.